# antonym of "belong to"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What's a verb that is the opposite of "belong [as a part] to"?

e.g.

A belongs to B.

I belong to my group.

then

B __ A?

My group __ me.

I initially thought about "contains". But I'm not sure if "contain" is an accurate word for describing this part-whole relationship. ("My group contains me"??)